# Paypal Express checkout make billing information prefilled

Tags: paypal, billing, express-checkout

While using paypal Express checkout using curl, can we pass some parameters to make the billing information like first name, last name, phone, city pre filled on the 'payment with debit card/credit card' page? I have all these details in my db and do not want the users to enter again on paypal payment page.

refernce- https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/blob/master/Merchant/sample/code/SetExpressCheckout.php

Comment: Already closed. got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using RestAPI you could create a Web Experience profile where you set the address_override

address_override    integer
"Determines if the PayPal pages should display the shipping address supplied in this call, rather than the shipping address on file with PayPal for this buyer. Displaying the address on file does not allow the buyer to edit the address. Allowed values: 0 or 1. When set to 0, the PayPal pages should display the address on file. When set to 1, the PayPal pages should display the addresses supplied in this call instead of the address from the buyer’s PayPal account."

Some info here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/

If you are using classic API there is something similar for the address override

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However with Express checkout i was able to do the same by setting ADDROVERRIDE=1 and then setting SHIPTONAME,SHIPTOSTREET,SHIPTOSTATE parameters. I got the Billing fields prefilled :)